# How to explicitly assign the position in Labeled[]?

Tags: labeling, labeled

From the documentation, `Labeled` accepts the positions 'Top, Bottom, Right, Left'. But this is too vague in some situations. So my question is whether it's possible to give the explicit position of labeling object respect to the labeled one?

A minimal example will be

```
Labeled[DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 2}}]], {"a", "b"}, {Bottom,
   Top}]
```

[image]

Let's say I want to put the label "b" at 3/4 to the left. I hope I could assign the position and alignment like `{Top,Scaled[.75]}`. What should I do?(Please do not use `FrameLabel` because the labeled object doesn't have to be a 'plot'. I just use it as an example here.) A very dumb workaround that I can think of is to add extra space before but that's just too ugly.

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have finer control on positioning if you use `Legended` in stead of `Labeled`:

```
Legended[DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 2}}]], 
 {Placed["a", Bottom], Placed["b", {{.85, 1.02}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Show` to combined graphics, including text.

Positions can be specified with scaled coordinates (relative to the plot):

```
Show[
 DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 2}}]],
 Graphics[{
   Text[Style["b", Medium], Scaled[{.75, 1.05}]],
   Text[Style["a", Medium], Scaled[{.5, -.08}]]
   }], ImagePadding -> 30, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Or with absolute coordinates:

```
Show[
 DensityPlot[x^2 + y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 2}}]],
 Graphics[{
   Text[Style["b", Medium], {0.5, 1.15}],
   Text[Style["a", Medium], {0, -1.2}]
   }], ImagePadding -> 30, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImageSize -> 300]
```

`ImagePadding` may need to be adjusted to make room for the labels.